# Symfony: How to access the user object early in execution

Tags: php, routes, symfony1, publishing

I have a custom routing class that checks versioning of an object to allow for creation of draft versions of pages that wont appear on the live site. When an admin clicks to preview a draft version of a page my PublishingHelper class on the front-end (called from the routing class) checks the user's permissions to see if they are allowed to view the draft version of this page.

I am using this code:

```
$context = sfContext::getInstance();
$user = $context->getUser();
```

But $user is NULL.

Does anyone have any ideas? All my searches seem to say this is the right way of getting the user object.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Maybe sfContext is not yet initialized. You could take a look at initialize() and loadFactories() (or similar).

Comment: sfContext is initialised (I checked with $context->hasInstance()). I tried "if ($user === null) $context->loadFactories()" but that sent it into a recursive loop, therefore it must be loadFactories which is kicking off the routing process.

Comment: I found the generated cache file for including the factories - "config_factories.yml.php". If I edit this file and put the factories['user'] bit above the factories['routing'] bit then the user object is initialised! ... Now the problem is that it doesnt have any id or details...

Comment: @Jon - yes I am. However the user object Ive got (from previous comment) returns null on $user->getGuardUser()

Comment: Have you tried the following, after your factories fix... sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments Till/Jon, Ive managed to fix this now. The factories fix didnt work because while the user class is instantiated none of the filters have run therefore I was left with a useless user object.

I solved my problems simply by taking pretty much all the code in the matchesUrl() function of my custom routing class and putting in a new function doRouting() in the same class. matchesUrl() now looks like this:

```
public function matchesUrl($url, $context = array())
{
  if (false === $parameters = parent::matchesUrl($url, $context))
  {
    return false;
  }

  $parameters['module'] = 'content';
  $parameters['action'] = 'route';

  $this->url            = $url;
  $this->context        = $context;

  return $parameters;
}
```

and the routing is deferred to after the factories and filters by using my "content" module/controller:

```
class contentActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeRoute(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $router = $this->getRoute();
    $router->doRouting($router->url, $router->context);
  }
```

And the doRouting() function now forwards directly to the appropriate module/action (correctly taking into account user permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing such a restrictions would be easier to implement as a filter: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/12-Filters

Comment: I think you're probably right. This way is working fine (as sort of a hacky-filter) so I wont change it, but will bear in mind for next time.